# Can't remove entity with JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to remove an entity from memory (at the moment I don't use DB) with JPA, when I use `remove` and then try to find the deleted entity it shows `null`, but when I use `findAll` method it retrieve all data (with removed entity)...

Profile.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;

    private Boolean restrictedAccess;

    private Boolean canValidate;

    // private Set<AccessField> accessFields = new HashSet<AccessField>();

    // private Set<AccessEntity> accessEntities = new HashSet<AccessEntity>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<AccessMenu> menuSections = new HashSet<AccessMenu>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
[getters and setters]
```

ProfileRepository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ProfileRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Profile save(Profile p) {
        p = this.entityManager.merge(p);
        this.entityManager.flush();
        return p;
    }

    public void delete(Long id){
        Profile profile = this.entityManager.find(Profile.class, id);
        this.entityManager.remove(profile);
    }

    public List<Profile> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Profile.class));
        return (List<Profile>) this.entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public Profile findById(Long id){
        return this.entityManager.find(Profile.class, id);
    }
}
```

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="profile/delete/{idProfile}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delete(@PathVariable String idProfile,RedirectAttributes ra, Model model){


        profileRepo.delete(Long.valueOf(idProfile));

        model.addAttribute("profiles", profileRepo.findAll());

        return "profile/list";
    }
```

Comment: why do you call Profile "delProfile = this.entityManager.merge(profile);" again in delete function?

Comment: Because I read somewhere that I must call merge to get the same transaction

Comment: By the way, even though deleteById is the right way to do it like in the example I gave in my answer, if you still do not want to change your code, the problem is that while deleting you are also saving another entity by calling "Profile delProfile = this.entityManager.merge(profile);" and deleting your newly created entity at the same time. So, your actual entity will not be deleted.

Comment: Try removing @Transactional(readOnly = true) and annotate with @Transaction alone? Did you try it?

Comment: Now I put @Transactional alone and didn't works. I will edit the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution, the problem was when I tried to remove `Profile`, `users` and `menuSections` have related data, so finally I put in `menuSections` a `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` and in `users` set `profile` property to `null`

Answer (score 1):

if you are are trying to delete an entity by using Id in the controller, do it like `profileRepo.deleteById(Long.valueOf(idProfile));`
 this, not like this `profileRepo.delete(profileRepo.findById(Long.valueOf(idProfile)));`

Also use your repository functions like these,

```
public void deleteArtistById(Long artistId) {
    Artist artist = manager.find(Artist.class, artistId);
    if (artist != null) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.remove(artist);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}


public void deleteArtist(Artist artist) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.remove(artist);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

You can take a look at this link for more detail:
 http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-delete-entity-object-in-jpa/

Comment: I think I cant use .getTransaction.begin() with @Transactional annotation, it throws me this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead` but thanks for the advice, I will edit the question with the new method

Comment: you can remove and try again without getTransaction() method if you are using @Transactional annotation. It is a copy paste from the link I shared, so you need to change it to make it work with your code.

Comment: I did it but doesn't works, when I use findAll() it finds the deleted registry